# Localization of $\Bbb k[x]$

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization

> Let $R= \Bbb K [x]$ and $S=\{x^n: n \in \Bbb Z, n \geq 0 \} $. Let $D$ be the localization of $R$ in $S$, that is $D = S^{-1}R = \{ \frac{r}{s}: r \in R, s\in S \}$. By using the Universal Property of Localization prove that $S^{-1}R = \Bbb K [x,x^{-1}]$.

I've managed to prove the equality by using a standart isomorphism between the two rings but I can't quite seem to grasp how to apply the Universal Property of Localization. As far as I can understand, by using the UPL we come to a conclusion of the form $S^{-1}R \cong \Bbb K [x,x^{-1}]$. From that point it is trivial to show the equality. But how do we end up there?

Any insights will be duly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: So the universal property of localizations says that the localization is a Ring with a map from the original ring and certain other properties (and that it is universal with this property). Show that $\mathbb{K}[x,x^{-1}]$ satisfies this property.

Comment: Those properties would be that :
1. If $s \in S$, then  $\theta(s)$ is a unit of $\Bbb Κ [x,x^{-1}]$.
2. If $r \in \ker \theta $, then $r \cdot s =0$ for some $s \in S$.
3. Every element of $\Bbb Κ [x,x^{-1}]$ is of the form $\theta (r) \theta (s) ^{-1}$ for some $r \in \Bbb Κ [x]$ and $s \in S$.
Right?

Comment: Yes, those are the properties.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thank you so very much!!!